# Test if an element already exists with ID in a ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#

I'd like to test to see if an object in my ConcurrentQueue is already added by use of an ID property.  I tried the following without much luck:

```
ConcurrentQueue<StrippedResponse> responses = new ConcurrentQueue<StrippedResponse>();
// Add elements to the responses object.
if (responses.Contains(e => e.ID == request.ID))
{
  // Do something special
}
```

Can I find/locate/test if an element exists using a ConcurrentQueue?  And if so how do I do that?  If that ability is not available to ConcurrentQueue what collection should I use that is thread safe while adding/enqueuing objects?

Comment: I think you want `responses.Where(e => e.ID == request.ID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you care about is existence try

```
if(responses.Any(e => e.ID == request.ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would override the Equals method and use the Any extension for a cleaner look.

```
public class StrippedResponse
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    ...

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ID == ((StrippedResponse)obj).ID;
    }
}


ConcurrentQueue<StrippedResponse> responses = new  ConcurrentQueue<StrippedResponse>();

public void YourMethod()
{
    // Add elements to the responses object.
    if (responses.Any(e => e.Equals(request)))
    {
      // Do something special
    }
}
```